# Javascript - How can I execute a function for a page from another page?

Tags: javascript, function, chat, global

So basically, I have to do a simple webchat which needs a admin user. He should be able to kick a webchat user out or remove messages from the chat. I've used php to remove the chat messages from the database. So that works.

While the messages are deleted, the users can still see the messages in the chat. Only after reloading the page, the messages are not shown anymore.

I created a javascript function which sets the chat message display to none. That works too but only from my chat page.

There are two important pages.

1. chatpage.html
2. adminpage.php

Code for javascript function:

```
$('#fadeoutmessage').live('click', function() {
    $('#chatline').css("display", "none");
});
```

This function works when called on chatpage.html. It doesn't work when called from adminpage.php.

Unfortunately, I'm forced to use jquery version 1.4.2 .

My question is how I can execute that function from adminpage.php to be executed on the chatpage.html.

Comment: You can't. The server can't tell the client to execute a script. You have a few options, as I see it: Either implement some kind of polling (i.e, you client "asks" the server every X seconds if any changes have been made to the database, and if so, update the chat) or implement a websocket solution, if possible (depends on the server you are running).

Comment: To go along with @Chris, if you want to explore different technologies, and haven't used them yet, Node.js and Socket.io work well together to easily make use of websockets to establish persistent connections so messages can be broadcast from the server to all connected clients (and from clients to the server), even after they've loaded a page. Socket.io provides a brief tutorial on how to do this here: https://socket.io/get-started/chat

Comment: As @Chris you can't - its like me from my end to execute script on your end = security breach. What you can do is create AJAX call that each client page executes - this uses your php to checks the DB for changes,then sends the result back to AJAX and depending on it executes given methods - like the hide/delete of messages. (And you want have to do anything from your admin page).

Comment: Why not just use Firebase. [Here's a tutorial!!](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5359-firebase-tutorial-real-time-chat)

Comment: @Chris I just looked at polling and tried a small example. It actually worked and I understand the use behind it. But I don't know how to code the request for my database (if something has changed) . Can you give me a little hint? As I said, it's just a simple webchat. It doesn't have to be a big thing. It's just for study. Thanks to everyone for your answers!